# Removing elements from binding list

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, bindinglist

In one of my projects I'm trying to remove an item from a list where the id is equal to the given id.

I have a `BindingList<T>` called `UserList`.

Lists have all the method `RemoveAll()`.

Since I have a `BindingList<T>`, I use it like that:

```
UserList.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.id == ID )
```

However, my list contains the same number of items as before.
Why it's not working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not working because you are working on a copy of the list which you created by calling `ToList()`.

`BindingList<T>` doesn't support `RemoveAll()`: it's a `List<T>` feature only, so:

```
IReadOnlyList<User> usersToRemove = UserList.Where(x => (x.id == ID)).
                                             ToList();

foreach (User user in usersToRemove)
{
    UserList.Remove(user);
}
```

We're calling `ToList()` here because otherwise we'll enumerate a collection while modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
UserList = UserList.Where(x => x.id == ID).ToList();
```

If you use `RemoveAll()` inside a generic class that you intend to be used to hold a collection of any type object, like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{

    internal List<T> InternalList;

    public SomeClass() { InternalList = new List<T>(); }

    public void RemoveAll(T theValue)
    {
        // this will work
        InternalList.RemoveAll(x =< x.Equals(theValue));
        // the usual form of Lambda Predicate 
        //for RemoveAll will not compile
        // error: Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of Type 'T' and 'T'
        // InternalList.RemoveAll(x =&amp;gt; x == theValue);
    }
}
```

This content is taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If there is just one item as unique ID inside bindinglist, the below simple code can work.

```
UserList.Remove(UserList.First(x=>x.id==ID));
```